# How to get lineage info of dataflow jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am new to dataflow and am trying to get the lineage information about any dataflow job, for an app I am trying to build. I am trying to fetch atleast the source and destination names from a job and if possible find out the transformation applied on the pcollection in the pipeline, something like a trace of the function calls.
I have been analyzing the logs for different kind of jobs, but could not figure out a definite way to fetch any of the informations I am looking for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this information from the graph itself. One way to do this would be to implement your own runner which delegates to the Dataflow runner.

For Dataflow, you could also use the fetch the job (whose steps will give the topology) from the service via the [Dataflow API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/get).

Comment: I have analysed the output of dataflow job describe for various kind of jobs, what I see is a problem is that there is no definite tag to identify the source or target. It could be the stage0, outpu0 temporary things. For example if you run the jdbctobq template job and hardcode the sourrce table in the code , there is no way to know the source details from any of the step details. This is just an example and unfortunately I am encountering similar situations for most of the jobs I am trying.

Comment: Correct. The v1beta3 protos do not preserve the composite structure, which is a downside. Sometimes things get stuck in display data that can be leveraged to determine the semantic meaning of a step. Short of that you might have to deserialize the java blobs.